# Multithreaded and singlethreaded code maintenance

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have an application which I would like to run either with multithreading (via OpenMP) or else as a singlethreaded one.

I have a `#define MT true //if true, then multithreaded, else singlethreaded` macro that is a switch between the two options.

Suppose in my single threaded application, there was an array:

```
int foo [5];
```

In the multithreaded cases, (suppose there are 4 threads), I have had to declare the above as:

```
int foo[4][5];
```

A function in the single threaded case whose declaration was:

```
void work_on_foo(int* foo){
    foo[4] = 2;
}
```

becomes

```
void work_on_foo(int thread, int** foo){
    foo[thread][4] = 2;
}
```

At the moment, to handle this code bloat, I am doing the brute for replication as follows:

```
#if MT
    void work_on_foo(int thread, int** foo){
#else
    void work_on_foo(int* foo){
#endif
#if MT
        foo[thread][4] = 2;
#else
        foo[4] = 2;
#endif
}
```

This is of course ugly. Is there a way to prevent this brute force way of code maintenance? The only other way seems to be to have two independent code bases, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: In cases like that I've used different header files to separate the code but still be able to keep shared code and then used config files to generate the correct code.

Comment: From your description the (maximum) number of threads is known when building your program.   In that case, I would simply treat the single threaded case as a special case where the number of threads is one.   Swap the arguments of your functions that take a `thread` argument so its last, and give that argument a default value of `1`.   At most, your functions simply check the received value of `thread` for validity before proceeding - no need to worry about implementing multiple thread and single threaded versions.

Comment: Code is written incorrectly. In well written code "business logic" part should not be aware if it is muti threading or not. If your code with main logic has argument `int thread` you are screwed anyway. IMO question is asked incorrectly and this qualifies for [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Peter, yes, in my case, the maximum number of threads is known at compile time. While your suggestion is good, it will still lead to unnecessary storage waste. In this case, 3 times storage is wasted for every data structure that needs thread separation.

Comment: @user6556709 for thread safety, would you not need to have thread-separate data structures and then access them using the thread index? If yes, could you let me know how you were able to have shared .cpp implementation files? That is precisely what my problem is.

Comment: @Tryer - how is having arrays (presumably the biggest user of storage) "wasting space" if one of the dimensions is set to 1????    The memory consumed by an array `int x[1][4]` is identical to the memory consumed by an array `int x[4]`.   The only difference is how elements are indexed (and variables used for the additional dimension, which will usually be trivial).   Unless you're on hardware with VERY limited resources (and if you're using OpenMP, you almost certainly don't) the difference will be insignificant.   Read up on "premature optimisation"./

Comment: @Peter, Ok, I think I see your point. So, in my case, if #define MT is false, I would need to have another static int const no_threads = 1; and then replicate each data structure these many times.

Comment: If the array's element with index `thread` is used only by the thread with given index, then you have a **thread-local data**. OpenMP has a well-defined notion of such data: being declared as `static int foo [5];`, the array becomes thread-local by using `#pragma omp threadprivate(foo)`. See more in this paper: http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-data.html.

Answer (score -1):

How about classes to handle them?
Create a base class with the desired interface and derive two classes, one for single thread, one for multihread. If you which to change you only need to change your factory. (Have a look at [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection))

Comment: let me look into it. But it still appears to me that I would have to reimplement it twice -- one for single threaded, one for multithreaded.

Comment: Well, youre doing this already. By using classes you're only seperating them by class, not with a #define. I dont think you can avoid using two different functions if you call them with different parameters